# How to evaluate the following complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm asked to evaluate the following complex integral

$$\oint_{C}^{}{\frac{z}{z^2+a^2}dz}\quad |a|<1$$

where C is the unit circle enclosing the origin.

The integrand loses analyticity when $z = \pm ia$, each of which lies interior to C.

However, we can utilize deformation of the contour and Cauchy's Theorem where $C=C_0-C_1-C_2=0$. Therefore we now need to evaluate

$$\oint_{C_1}^{}{\frac{z}{z^2+a^2}dz} + \oint_{C_2}^{}{\frac{z}{z^2+a^2}dz}\quad |a|<1$$

However, I don't know how to evaluate the above integrals, and would love some advice on how to do so.

Comment: You can use Cauchy's integral formula for those two integrals.

Comment: You can use residue theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't see how I can manipulate the integrand into the form $\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$

Comment: @HenryW We haven't progressed that far in my complex class.

Comment: Would setting $z'=z^2$ and $a'=a^2$ work?

Comment: Factor $z^2 + a^2$. $$\frac{z}{z^2+a^2} = \frac{\frac{z}{z+ia}}{z-ia}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

Yet another approach is to use partial fraction expansion and write

$$\frac{z}{z^2+a^2}=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{z-ia}+\frac{1}{z+ia}\right)$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z}{z^2+a^2}\,dz&=\frac12\int_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{1}{z-ia}+\frac{1}{z+ia}\right)\,dz\\\\
&=\frac12 \int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z-ia}\,dz+\frac12 \int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z+ia}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac12 \left(2\pi i+2\pi i\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

We can evaluate the integral of interest by evaluating the [Residue at Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity).  Let $f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+a^2}$, then the residue at infinity of $f$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(f(z),\infty\right)&=-\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right),0\right)\\\\
&=-\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{a^2z^2+1}\right)\\\\
&=-1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,dz&=-2\pi i\, \text{Res}\left(f(z),\infty\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Using the factorization given by Daniel in the comments and Cauchy's Integral Theorem the integrals evaluate to

$$2\pi i(\frac{ia}{2ia})+2\pi i(\frac{-ia}{-2ia}) = 2\pi i$$

Comment: Good. Here's another trick: By Cauchy's integral theorem, $$I(R) = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{z}{z^2+a^2}\,dz$$ is independent of $R$ as long as $R > \lvert a\rvert$. Now $$\biggl\lvert\frac{1}{z} - \frac{z}{z^2+a^2}\biggr\rvert = \biggl\lvert\frac{a^2}{z(z^2+a^2)}\biggr\rvert < \frac{2}{\lvert z\rvert^3}$$ for $\lvert z\rvert > 2$, so $$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{1}{z} - \frac{z}{z^2+a^2}\,dz = 0.$$ By independence of $R$, it follows that $$\int_C \frac{z}{z^2+a^2}\,dz = \int_C \frac{1}{z}\,dz.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer That's really cool! What's the intuition behind your second mathematical statement?

Comment: By "second mathematical statement" you mean the $\bigl\lvert \frac{1}{z} - \frac{z}{z^2+a^2}\bigr\rvert$ line? The idea behind looking at that is that rational functions have a pretty simple asymptotic behaviour at $\infty$, and as long as the contour encloses all poles in $\mathbb{C}$, we can replace the integrand with the relevant part of the asymptotic expansion without changing the integral. A pertinent key term here is "residue at $\infty$".

Comment: Correct. Got it - thanks!